# Good ideas for Tonka Beans

Tags: baking, beans

My girlfriend loves the taste of Tonka beans, so I got her some for Christmas. We are however struggling to find that many recipes involving them, and the ones we have found seem to vary from saying use very little (i.e. 1 tsp of grated) to a whole bean.

Does anyone have any experience with Tonka beans and pointers for where some good recipes may be, or which foods they work best in?

Thanks

Comment: A little research turns up the fact that they are high in coumarin, and when consumed in large quantities can result in severe internal hemorrhage.  Be careful.

Comment: Personally in the past I've used them in chocolate recipes such as dark chocolate tart where the tonka helps intensify the chocolate flavour while creating an amazing smell. Also alongside vanilla in panacotta, creme anglaise and creme brulee, where I've found both smells and flavours really compliment each other. Usage wise I've tended to use a whole bean for either 1 tart or 8 panacotta.

Comment: #John Feltz, you could say that about almost anything, and I doubt very much that anyone would consume a large amount of Tonka beans.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some great background to the [Tonka bean](http://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2010/11/the-tonka-bean-an-ingredient-so-good-it-has-to-be-illegal/65616/) .  Try a few shavings in ice cream.